# OAuth 2 v2 cert to System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0

How can I create a System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 object? from cert JSON at:

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/certs

The X509Certificate2 constructor works with bytes from:

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs

Using example which uses OAuth 2 v1 cert:

https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-verifytoken-csharp/blob/master/verifytoken.ashx.cs

Comment: The v2 looks like bare rsa modulus and exponent you could use to initialize the rsa crypto serivce provider. From there you have a long journey to x509 cert.